# Can't get text to center?

Tags: css, xhtml

I have a `div` wrapped around a couple `span`'s and using JS to make the span's fade in and out (for testimonials). Everything works, except I can't get the `span` text to center within the `div`. Here's the relevant code:

HTML -

```
<div class="slideshow">
    <span style="font-size:12px; color:#333333; font-family:Lucida Grande,Lucida Sans Unicode,Calibri,Arial,sans-serif;">Hi</span>
    <span style="font-size:12px; color:#333333; font-family:Lucida Grande,Lucida Sans Unicode,Calibri,Arial,sans-serif;">Goodbye</span>
</div><br />
```

And here's the slideshow CSS -

```
.slideshow {
width:940px;
height:64px;
background-image:url(../images/quotes.png);
}
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Oh and yes I've tried `text-align:center;` with no luck.

[Edit] I'd like to add I've also tried adding in `!important` with no change.

Comment: I'm sorry for the wait David had to walk my younger brother to the bus. Here's the fiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/v7EuF/

Comment: no worries. Thanks for adding the link (I'd suggest editing into your question, too, so any late-comers don't get left out if they miss the comments).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to apply `text-align: center` to the containing `<div>`, and not do anything that causes the `<span>`s to be rendered as a block (such as `float`ing them). Absolute positioning would also pull elements out of normal flow so they wouldn't be influenced by text-align.

---

**Update** : Now a working example has been provided, we can see what is going on. The span elements are being absolutely positioned by the plugin:

```
$slides.css({position: 'absolute', top:0, left:0}).hide()
```

Looks like you will need to rethink the layout logic the plugin is using.

Comment: What else would cause `<span>` to be rendered as a block? I'm not floating anything. And I tried adding `text-align: center` to `.slideshow` ... no luck.

Comment: Did he not say he tried that? And he is not floating anything. And why the upvotes???

Comment: @Matt Untsaiyi you can use the css property "display: block" to display almost any element as a block element. This is a very common thing to do. If you want to make double sure the spans are displayed inline you could add "display: inline", but normally this should not be neccessary.

Comment: @Yehonatan — no, he said he was using `text-align: center`, but not where, and he didn't say he wasn't floating anything. Whatever is causing the problem isn't in the code that is being shown.

Comment: @David He didn't say that he had his computer plugged in either.

Comment: He didn't say it was absolutely positioned either — but it was.

Comment: I'm stuck. I've tried adding `left:50%` to `$slides.css` and although it centers, the slide is broken and all my `<span>`s appear at once.

Answer (score 5):

I tested your code and just added

```
.slideshow {
    text-align: center; 
}
```

and the text centered just fine.

Maybe you've got a typo, or a css definition somewhere else that overrides your text-align?

**Edit**

I did an "inspect-element" of the fiddle posted and here are the css definitions i got:

```
<div class="slideshow" style="position: relative; ">
    <span style="font-size: 12px; color: rgb(51, 51, 51); font-family: 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Calibri, Arial, sans-serif; position: absolute; z-index: 3; top: 0px; left: 0px; display: block; width: 13px; height: 15px; opacity: 0.275808; ">Hi</span>
    <span style="font-size: 12px; color: rgb(51, 51, 51); font-family: 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Calibri, Arial, sans-serif; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; display: block; width: 52px; height: 15px; z-index: 2; opacity: 0.724192; ">Goodbye</span>
</div>

element.style {
    color: #333;
    display: block;
    font-family: 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Calibri, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    height: 15px;
    left: 0px;
    opacity: 1;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    width: 52px;
    z-index: 3;
}
```

I would say the "display: block" is your problem.

Comment: It, perhaps obviously, should work. But it doesn't in his situation (which I think is the point @David Dorward makes in his comment to his own answer). It's also why I asked the OP to post a live demo somewhere, so we could try and find out what it is, elsewhere, that's causing his problem(s).

Comment: Yes I tested the above code and it worked fine, so it has to be somewhere else. I've included a fiddle link (http://jsfiddle.net/v7EuF/) that reproduces the same problem.

Comment: If that element is set to `display: block;` then adding `margin: 0 auto;` should probably work, rather than trying to fight the plug-in that appears to be adding the extra styles.